# Bootstrap IOS Iphone overexceed div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm running in troubles by make my website responsiv.
With my OnePlus 5T everything looks nice and runs smoothly.

But on IOS I think IPhone 6<. My buttons go out of my divs (right site).
Maybe just a keyword to google or a nice hint. 
I'm going crazy with this issue.

Framework: 
Bootstrap v3.3.7

Bug 1:

[image: Bug1]

Bug 2:
[image: Bug2]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, your table is wider than your iPhone screen. Try to use [responsive tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables)

Comment: Hey Syfer, thanks for your help. I have tried, but it doesnt affect anything. On Android and Iphone 7 the Table is wrapped in the div, with no problems. And with the Responsiv View of chrome with a tiny screen, it fits. Maybe a old version of Safari? How can I make it compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats why you need media queries. Those elements have a combined width which is larger that of screen and parent div. 
Use media query and change the layout for mobile devices to fix https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOQG4.jpg, and use responsive tables of bootstrap to fix issue 2.